# How to detect the movement of Face in circular fashion..I'm using AVFoundation for taking multiple snapshots of the face

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera, avfoundation

In My project, i need to capture 20 to 30 photos of a single person. what im doing is

```
    let cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.customView.frame
    self.customView.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
```

To capture a photo.

```
   @IBAction func cameraButtonTouch(_ sender: Any) {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
   }
```

And im calling this function every sec using Timer. Problem is when the face didnt move, all the 20 captured photos are same.

I dont want to do this.. is there any way to detect that the face is moving and its direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time

Comment: Can you please elaborate if you know about that.

Comment: @Joker have you found a solution to your circular face movement question? Maybe a link to some GitHub repo with code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you want to build something similar to Apple's Face ID.

You should use a Face tracking component (like the one @Ben Rockey suggested in his comment, but there are others). From there, you need to get the information about the angle of the face. The angle of the face is represented with roll, pitch, and yaw.

[image: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tsang_Ing_Ren/publication/279291928/figure/fig1/AS:292533185462272@1446756754388/Orientation-of-the-head-in-terms-of-pitch-roll-and-yaw-movements-describing-the-three.png]

What I would recommend is to track the values for pitch and yaw you're getting from the face detection. Then, capture photos only for the 30 cases which correspond to your definition of a "circular fashion".

This can be done in a multitude of ways. If you have a more specific question, please edit this one or post another question.

Comment: sorry for the late response.. Yes this is exactly what i needed..can you please explain a bit to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's Vision API to achieve face detection. However, Vision only detects yaw and roll rotations:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnfaceobservation